# `cfg` which is always true / false?

Tags: rust

For testing purpose I need `cfg` which is always true / false.
For true I use

```rust
#[ cfg( target_pointer_width = "64") ]
...
```

But obviously it is not general enough.
What is optimal way of expressing `cfg` to get necessary value?

Comment: Why can't you just omit the `cfg` directive?

Comment: `any(foo, not(foo))` is always true. `#[cfg(any(foo, not(foo)))]` will always evaluate

Comment: @isaactfa for testing purpose. For example in test of a macro.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just do this for a `cfg` option that is always true:

```
#[cfg(all())]
fn main() {
    println!("It works!");
}
```

And if you need a `cfg` option that is always false you can use:

```
#[cfg(any())]
fn main() {
    println!("It disappears!");
}
```

Comment: I used to write `#[cfg(xxx)]` to comment out some block of code, but this looks nicer, and can be changed from _on_ to _off_ just by overwriting two characters.

Comment: Amazing! That's what I had been looking for.